# HTTP ERROR 500 para ingreso con login PHP

Tags: php, http

Tengo el siguiente problema: HTTP ERROR 500

Estoy armando un sistema de login con mail y contraseña, el cual funcionaba con otro sistema.

He actualizado el sistema, pero el mismo no funciona con el sistema nuevo, cuando quiero ingresar, salta el error.

Este es el script que estoy usando:

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    if (isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["password"])) {
        if ($_POST["email"]!="" && ($_POST["password"]!="")) {
            include "conexion.php";

            $user_id=null;
            $sql1= "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email=\"$_POST[email]\" AND password=\"$_POST[password]\"";
            $query= $con->query($sql1);
            while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
                $user_id=$r["id"];
                break;
            }
            if($user_id==null){
                print "<script>alert(\"Usuario o contraseña incorrectos\");window.location='../index.php';</script>";
            }else{
                session_start();
                $_SESSION["user_id"]=$user_id;
                print "<script>window.location='../inicio.php';</script>";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Este mismo script es el que tengo en el sistema anterior y funciona correctamente.

De hecho, al eliminar la parte del código php en las páginas a entrar con este login, todo funciona correctamente.

No logro encontrar el error.

Este es el código del formulario que estoy usando:

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form" name="login" action="php/ingreso.php" method="post">

        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Iniciar Sesión</h1>

        <label for="email" class="sr-only">Correo Electrónico</label>

        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Correo Electrónico" required autofocus>

        <label for="password" class="sr-only">Contraseña</label>

        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Contraseña" required>

        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit">Ingresar</button>

        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que puedo ver, incluyes `conexion.php` pero a `$con` nunca lo igualas a la función que realiza dicha conexión (no sé cómo se llama). Analicé tu código y solo encuentro ese posible problema (si es erróneo, solo dímelo y elimino la respuesta)

Comment: $con = new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db);
if ($con->connect_error){
 die($con->connect_error());}

Ese sería la variable $con en la conexion.php. arriba están los datos de usuario, pass, BD y demás

Comment: Pero para eso no sería necesario usar una consulta mysqli_query? Con esa conexión yo usualmente utilizo: function dbConnect (){
    $conn = null;
    $host = 'localhost';
    $db =   'db_name';
    $user = 'user';
    $pwd =  'pass';
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db, $user, $pwd);
        //echo 'Connected succesfully.<br>';
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo '<p>Cannot connect to database !!</p>';
        exit;
    }
    return $conn;
 }